# How to call C functions from a .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a website(client) with a bunch of buttons, the site sends the value of those controls to a .js file(sever) through a websocket. Both are connected through the same port I'm using node.js and ws.

How do I call a C function from the .js file in order to perform server side calculations? Is that even possible?

Comment: It seems that basic Google search research would have given you the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The key word here is “Foreign Function Interface”, or FFI for short. It turns out that there's [a package on NPM called `ffi`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ffi) that would probably do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

V8 (which node.js uses) has functionality that may help.

https://code.google.com/p/v8-juice/wiki/BindingFunctions